# Show that there exists a sequence $ (a_n)\subset T$ for which $|a_n-a| \lneq 1/3^n $ for all n

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf, supremum-and-infimum

Let $T \subset R$, Let $ a= sup(T)  $, and $ a\notin T $. Then Show that there exists a sequence $ (a_n)\subset T$ for which $|a_n-a| \lneq 1/3^n $ for all n.

I know it is not too hard to find a sequence which converges to a, but I get to know how to find such $a_n $sequence which satisfy $|a_n-a| \lneq 1/3^n $ for all n.

Comment: Take a sequence $\{a_n\}$ that converges to $a$, choose $N$ so that $|a_n-a|<3^{-n}$ for $n\geqslant N$, and consider the sequence $a_N, a_{N+1},\ldots.$

Comment: @Math1000 $N$ does not necessarily exist for an arbitrary sequence $a_n$. And finding a sequence for which $N$ exists is equivalent to the problem posed.

Comment: @SaritaSharma Hint: prove that $T_n = T \cap (a - 1/3^n, a + 1/3^n)$ is infinite for all $n$,  then pick any $a_n \in T_n$.

Comment: @dxiv The question says "I know it is not too hard to find a sequence which converges to $a$" - so that is a natural starting point for a hint...

Comment: @Math1000 Point was that you said `take *a* sequence`, but that cannot be just *any* sequence. Say one tries to `take a sequence` $a_n = a - 3^{-n} - 1/n$ which converges to $a$ just fine. But there will exist *no* $N$ such as $|a_n - a| \lt 3^{-n}$ for $n \ge N$. So how does one find a sequence such that you hinted at? That's essentially equivalent to the question being asked.

Comment: To be more precise - "Take a sequence $a_n$ with each $a_n\in T\ldots$"

Answer (score 2):

Let $(f(n))_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be any sequence of positive numbers converging to $0. $ Let $a=\sup T.$

From the def'n of $\sup,$ no $b<a$ is an upper bound for $T.$ So for each $n\in \mathbb N$ there exists $a_n\in T$ with $a_n>a-f(n).$

And also $a_n\leq a$ (because $a_n\in T$ and $a$ is an upper bound for $T.$)

So  $\;a-f(n)<a_n\leq a,$ which implies $\;0\leq |a-a_n|=a-a_n<f(n).$

In particular we may take $f(n)=3^{-n}$ for each $n\in \mathbb N.$